# Tkinter 2 button placed in same place

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

I'm trying to program with gui . Also i used tkinter designer and trying to make gui with 2 page.When i run program it shows page 1 but button of first page and button of second page appear in same coordinate, and second page 2 is placed right on it . How do i fix this

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Button, PhotoImage

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH1 = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\interface-py\exp99\build\assets\frame0")
def relative_to_assets1(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH1 / Path(path)
ASSETS_PATH2 = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\interface-py\exp99\build\assets\frame1")
def relative_to_assets2(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH2 / Path(path)
def create_page_1(window):
    global image_image_1
    global entry_image_1 
    global entry_image_2 
    global button_image_1
    canvas = Canvas(
        window,
        bg="#FFFFFF",
        height=625,
        width=1000,
        bd=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        relief="ridge"
    )
    # canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
    image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets1("image_1.png"))
    image_1 = canvas.create_image(
        839.0,
        312.0,
        image=image_image_1
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        122.0,
        56.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Password Checker",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault ExtraBold", 45 * -1)
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        157.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Username",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault Bold", 18 * -1)
    )

    entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets1("entry_1.png"))
    entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(
        329.0,
        242.0,
        image=entry_image_1
    )
    entry_1 = Entry(
        bd=0,
        bg="#FFFFFF",
        fg="#000716",
        highlightthickness=0,
        font=("RobotoFlex Regular", 18 * -1)  
    )
    entry_1.place(
        x=128.514874458313,
        y=215.0,
        width=400.970251083374,
        height=58.0
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        133.0,
        228.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Enter your  username",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlex Regular", 14 * -1)
    )

    #logical functions starts from here


    def getInput(): #input from button & calculations 
        username=entry_1.get()
        password=entry_2.get()
        print("Username: ",username)
        print("Password: ",password)
        print("Simple check :",passwordCheck(password))
        print("Davhtsal :",characterCheck(password))
        print("Daraalal :",positionCheck(password))
        print("percent :",percent)
        a = (percent*100)/10
        print("huvi :",a)
        show_page(2)
    percent = 0
    ##simple check starts from here

    def passwordCheck(password): #check simple password func
        global percent
        special = "!@#$%^&*()_+"  #tusgai temdegtuud aguulsn string
        up = 0 #tom usgiin too
        low = 0 #jijig usgiin too
        spcl = 0 #tusgai temdegtiin too
        count = 0 #too
        for i in password :
            if i.isupper() : #herev tom useg bol
                up += 1
            elif i.islower() : #jijg usg bol
                low += 1
            elif i in special : #temdegt bol
                spcl += 1
            else: #ugui bol too baina
                count += 1
        percent = percent + (len(password) - 12)   # 10 oos desh orh burt 1 eer nemegdene
        # print(percent)
        if up>=2 :
                percent +=2     #2
        if low>=2 :
                percent +=2     #2
        if spcl>=1 :
                percent +=2     #2
        if count >=2 :
                percent +=2     #2

        if up>=2 and low>=2 and spcl>=1 and count>=2 and len(password)>=12:
            return 'Passed' #engiin nuhtsuliig davsan msm ugnu

        #herev nuhtsul hangaagui uyd haygdsn nuhtsuliig butsaana
        else :
            if len(password)<=12:
                return 'Urt 12 oos ih baih ystoi.'
            elif up<=1:
                return 'Tom temdegt dor 2 hayj baina'
            elif low<=1: 
                return 'Jijig temdegt dor hayj 2 baina'
            elif spcl<1:
                return 'Tusgai temdegt dor hayj 1 baina'
            else :
                return 'Too dor hayj 2 baina'

    def characterCheck(password): # usgiin davhtsal 
        global percent
        character  = {}  #davhtsliig uusgeh dic
        for char in password:   #dic uusgne
            if char in character:
                character[char] += 1
            else:
                character[char] = 1
        count = 0 #toolur
        for i in character.values() : 
            if i>=2 : #hervee temdegt 2 oos deesh davhatssan bol
                count += i
              # davhtsagui bol 1 eer nemegdn
        #hamgiin bagdaa 3 demtegt 2 oos deehs oroh bolojmtoi
        if count >= len(character.values()):
            return 'Adilhan temdegtiin too ih baina'
        else :
            return 'Passed'

    def check(a,b): #2 temdegtiig daraallsn esehiig shalgana
        count = 0
        characters = "!@#$%^&*()_+|\:;'<>?/~"
        a_asc = ord(a)
        b_asc = ord(b)
        if a_asc == b_asc or abs(a_asc - b_asc) == 1 or abs(a_asc-b_asc) == 32 or abs(a_asc-b_asc)==33:
            count += 1
        elif (a in characters) and (b in characters) and abs(characters.index(a)-characters.index(b))==1:
            count += 1
        return count

    def positionCheck(password): #daraallig shalgana
        global percent
        ll = len(password)
        count = 0
        for i in range(ll-1):
            count += check(password[i],password[i+1])
            # print("{}, {} : {}".format(password[i],password[i+1],count))
        count += 1
        pp = (count/len(password))*100
        # percent += ((100-pp)//10)
        if pp<=40 :
            return 'Passed'
        else :
            return 'Usguud daraallsn bn'

    #Simple check ends here



    #logical functions ends  here
    button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets1("button_1.png"))

    button_1 = Button(
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=getInput,
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_1.place(
        x=117.0,
        y=500.0,
        width=424.0,
        height=45.0
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        304.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Password\n",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault Bold", 18 * -1)
    )

    entry_image_2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets1("entry_2.png"))
    entry_bg_2 = canvas.create_image(
        329.0,
        389.0,
        image=entry_image_2
    )
    entry_2 = Entry( # entry added
        bd=0,
        bg="#FFFFFF", #bg changed 2 white
        fg="#000716",
        highlightthickness=0,
        font=("RobotoFlex Regular", 18 * -1) #font added 
    )
    entry_2.place(
        x=128.514874458313,
        y=360.0,
        width=400.970251083374,
        height=58.0,
    )

    canvas.create_text(
        133.0,
        375.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Enter your  password",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlex Regular", 14 * -1)
    )
    return canvas

# Page 2
def create_page_2(window):
    global image_image_2
    global button_image_2
    canvas = Canvas(
        window,
        bg="#FFFFFF",
        height=625,
        width=1000,
        bd=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        relief="ridge"
    )
    # canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
    image_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets2("image_1.png"))
    image_2 = canvas.create_image(
        839.0,
        312.0,
        image=image_image_2
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        122.0,
        56.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Password Checker",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault ExtraBold", 45 * -1)
    )
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        157.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Simple checking\n",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault Black", 18 * -1)
    )
    
    button_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets2("button_2.png"))
    def button_cmd2():
        print("button2 clicked")
        show_page(1)
    button_2 = Button(
        image=button_image_2,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=button_cmd2,
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_2.place(
        x=117.0,
        y=500.0,
        width=424.0,
        height=45.0
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        190.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Simple check",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        222.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Dawhtsal\n",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        253.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Daraalal",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        285.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Percent\n",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        329.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Advanced checking",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault Black", 18 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        362.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Brute force",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        394.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Rockyou\n",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    canvas.create_text(
        117.0,
        424.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Dictionary",
        fill="#5F636D",
        font=("RobotoFlexNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalNormalDefault SemiBold", 16 * -1)
    )
    
    return canvas

# Controller function to switch between pages
def show_page(page_num):
    if page_num == 1:
        canvas_1.pack()
        canvas_2.pack_forget()
    elif page_num == 2:
        canvas_2.pack()
        canvas_1.pack_forget()
        # canvas_2.pack()

# Main application
window = Tk()
window.geometry("1000x625")
window.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")

canvas_1 = create_page_1(window)
canvas_2 = create_page_2(window)

# Add buttons or other elements to switch between pages
# button_to_page_1 = Button(window, text="Go to Page 1", command=lambda: show_page(1))
# button_to_page_1.pack()

# button_to_page_2 = Button(window, text="Go to Page 2", command=lambda: show_page(2))
# button_to_page_2.pack()

# Initially show Page 1
show_page(1)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

I just want to make gui that switch between 2 pages but buttons are placed in same coordinate and just last button appears . When i change coordinate of button2 button1 isjust on that coordinate

Comment: I don't think all of this code is needed to reproduce your issue. Please provide a [mre] and take the [tour] if you haven't yet already. Also take a look in [ask] in the [help] to higher your chances for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You create the two buttons as children of the root `window` because you do not specify the master of them, so the last created one will be shown since both are put in the same position and have same size.

I think you want to create them inside their corresponding canvas and put them into the canvas using `canvas.create_window(...)` instead:

```py
def create_page_1(window):
    ...
    button_1 = Button(
        canvas,  # master is the canvas
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=getInput,
        relief="flat"
    )
    canvas.create_window(117, 500, window=button_1, anchor="nw", width=424, height=45)
    ...

def create_page_2(window):
    ...
    button_2 = Button(
        canvas,
        image=button_image_2,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=button_cmd2,
        relief="flat"
    )
    canvas.create_window(117, 500, window=button_2, anchor="nw", width=424, height=45)
    ...
```